# How to get PortalId into sql script for 2sxc visual query

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I need to run a sql script in a 2sxc visual query.

I can do "where portalid = 709"

But, to use this in any portal, how do I automatically the the PortalId into the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the token `[Portal:PortalId]` in your sql ;)

For other token examples, like `[QueryString:xyz]` see https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Eav.DataSources.Sql.html

Comment: Thanks.  I came back to insert my own answer.  I actually found the answer in https://docs.2sxc.org/specs/lookup/placeholder-tokens.html.  I couldn't find it in the page you referenced, but it works just find.